# how to get numpy array from a tensor in a custom loss function

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, gradient, valueerror, loss-function

I'm trying to create my custom loss function, but I need to extract numpy arrays from tensors:

```
def generator_loss(gen_output, target):
    
    target_feature_image = np.zeros(target.shape)
    gen_feature_image = np.zeros(gen_output.shape)

    target_feature_image = daugman_feature_extractor(target.numpy())
    gen_feature_image = daugman_feature_extractor(gen_output.shape.numpy())
    
    return l1_loss(target_feature_image, gen_feature_image)
```

I got this error:

```
...
File "/var/folders/6z/93vfmb1930j2ys97s5xf8tp00000gn/T/ipykernel_28556/304022351.py", line 6, in generator_loss  *
    target_feature_image = daugman_feature_extractor(target.numpy())

    AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I've read that someone has used 'tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)', but actually I still get some troubles:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...

      6 gen_l1_loss = generator_loss(gen_output, input_image)
      8 generator_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_l1_loss,
      9                                       generator.trainable_variables)
---> 11 generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_gradients,
     12                                       generator.trainable_variables))
     14 with summary_writer.as_default():
     15     tf.summary.scalar('gen_l1_loss', gen_l1_loss, step=step//1000)


File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/optimizer.py:1222, in Optimizer.apply_gradients(self, grads_and_vars, name, skip_gradients_aggregation, **kwargs)
   1218 experimental_aggregate_gradients = kwargs.pop(
   1219     "experimental_aggregate_gradients", True
   1220 )
   1221 if not skip_gradients_aggregation and experimental_aggregate_gradients:
-> 1222     grads_and_vars = self.aggregate_gradients(grads_and_vars)
   1223 return super().apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/optimizer.py:1184, in Optimizer.aggregate_gradients(self, grads_and_vars)
   1182     return grads_and_vars
   1183 else:
-> 1184     return optimizer_utils.all_reduce_sum_gradients(grads_and_vars)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/utils.py:33, in all_reduce_sum_gradients(grads_and_vars)
     24 """Returns all-reduced gradients aggregated via summation.
     25 
     26 Args:
   (...)
     30   List of (gradient, variable) pairs where gradients have been all-reduced.
     31 """
     32 grads_and_vars = list(grads_and_vars)
---> 33 filtered_grads_and_vars = filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
     34 if filtered_grads_and_vars:
     35     if tf.__internal__.distribute.strategy_supports_no_merge_call():

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/utils.py:77, in filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
     75 if not filtered:
     76     variable = ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],)
---> 77     raise ValueError(
     78         f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "
     79         f"Provided `grads_and_vars` is {grads_and_vars}."
     80     )
     81 if vars_with_empty_grads:
     82     logging.warning(
     83         "Gradients do not exist for variables %s when minimizing the "
     84         "loss. If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to "
     85         "provide a `loss` argument?",
     86         ([v.name for v in vars_with_empty_grads]),
     87     )

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv2d_8/kernel:0', 'conv2d_9/kernel:0', 'batch_normalization_14/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_14/beta:0', 'conv2d_10/kernel:0', 'batch_normalization_15/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_15/beta:0', 'conv2d_11/kernel:0', 'batch_normalization_16/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_16/beta:0', 'conv2d_transpose_10/kernel:0', 'batch_normalization_17/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_17/beta:0', 'conv2d_transpose_11/kernel:0', 'batch_normalization_18/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_18/beta:0', 'conv2d_transpose_12/kernel:0', 'batch_normalization_19/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_19/beta:0', 'conv2d_transpose_14/kernel:0', 'conv2d_transpose_14/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_8/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4, 3, 64) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[-1.71476584e-02, -3.07616275e-02,  1.31781511e-02, ...,
          -1.54286949e-02,  1.64207630e-02, -1.88769363e-02],
         [ 2.56394781e-02, -2.13431679e-02,  1.10863149e-02, ...,
           2.45703757e-02, -1.47912614e-02,  4.67250571e-02],
         [ 1.99869368e-02, -1.48592517e-02, -5.33975195e-03, ...,
           4.60469313e-02, -3.09081636e-02,  3.15627530e-02]],
```

Is there any way to get numpy arrays in a loss function?
I've read some posts where they suggested to use some backend utilities or to use 'pure TF for custom loss', but I didn't understand how to do it.

Comment: Use pure TF for this or disable graph mode